# expectation of the log of the binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose $X\sim binomial (n,0.5)$ and set $Y=log(X)$ (base 2 is better, but any base would do).  How do I compute the expectation of $Y$, or find a good lower bound?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a problem with your question. The standard support (alphabet) of a binomial distribution is $k\in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$. But for $k=0$, $Y$ takes an infinite value. Could you spell out in full the binomial distribution as you intend it?

Comment: You are right.  I need to define $Y=log(X+\alpha)$, and this is already answered in Mathoverflow http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145678/expected-value-of-logarithm-of-a-binomial-random-variable  .